# Issue Retrieving Repo Tag by SHA with GitHub REST API

Tags: github, github-api

I've an issue with the ["Get a Tag"](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/tags#get-a-tag) API by the tag SHA.

As example, retrieving the SHA from the repo's tag list API ([ist-repository-tags](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-tags)), I'm not able to retrieve the detail of the tag providing the returned SHA.

You can reproduce the issue using as example the repo https://github.com/octokit/graphql-action:

1. Retrive a tag from the tag list endpoint:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/graphql-action/tags?per_page=1"
```

return

```
[
  {
    "name": "v2.2.22",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/graphql-action/zipball/refs/tags/v2.2.22",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/graphql-action/tarball/refs/tags/v2.2.22",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "975fed23f983de9aa6f637f9875f94c6fb0a4255",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/graphql-action/commits/975fed23f983de9aa6f637f9875f94c6fb0a4255"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjEzNzE3NjcyOnJlZnMvdGFncy92Mi4yLjIy"
  }
```

Try to retrieve the retails:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/graphql-action/git/tags/975fed23f983de9aa6f637f9875f94c6fb0a4255"
```

return

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#get-a-tag"
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe try asking on the [github community](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/) as well.